# My django keep looping the code when runserver

Tags: django

Sorry if the question is really newbie, just learn programming
i put this in my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from . import func

class Materials(models.Model):
    typeId = models.IntegerField()
    typeName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.FloatField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-typeId')

def __str__(Self):
    return self.typeId


def insert_data_once():
    rows = func.material_id()
    for row in rows:
        data = Materials(typeId = row[0], typeName = row[1], price = func.sell_min(row[0]))
        data.save()

insert_data_once()
```

here is func.py

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import sqlite3

def material_id():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('eve.db')
    command = 'SELECT DISTINCT invTypeMaterials.materialTypeID, invTypes.typeName FROM invTypeMaterials ' \
              'INNER JOIN invTypes ON invTypeMaterials.materialTypeID = invTypes.typeID ' \
              'WHERE invTypes.Published = 1'
    result = conn.execute(command)
    rows = result.fetchall()
    return rows

def sell_min(type_id):
    URL = 'https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid=' + str(
        type_id) + '&regionlimit=10000002&usesystem=30000142'
    minerals_price = requests.get(URL)
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(minerals_price.content)
    for child in root[0][0][1].iter('min'):
        sell_min = child.text
    return float(sell_min)
```

where i should run the insert_data_once function in models.py, the fuction keep looping and cant run manage.py runserver

thank you

Comment: Do you want to run this code one time (the very first time the application is started), or every time the application is started?

Comment: i want to run the code 1 time only, when  application started i need interact to update the database